# How to apply backgroundTint to AppCompatButton in Dialog?

Tags: android, background, android-button, android-appcompat, tint

I have a `DialogFragment` that contains a `Button`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_wishlist_rename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/WishlistDialogButton"
    android:text="@string/rename" />
```

The theme is defined like this:

```
<style name="WishlistDialogButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/default_blue</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/default_blue</item>
</style>
```

When I just embed the Fragment within the layout of my `Activity` everything works fine: I get a Material Design raised button with white text and blue background.

However, when the Fragment is used as a dialog the backgroundTint is not applied anymore: I get a Material Design raised button with white text **but with grey** background.

Is there a way to fix this - preferably without creating all the drawables from scratch or importing some third party library?